# Creating a virtual lan

Tags: vlan

There are numerous xfinity hotspots throughout the apartment building I am responsible for. Rather than install a number of wireless access points for building operations, i.e. locks, access control, laundry, cameras, etc. I'd like to create a virtual network from those xfinity hotspots where any of the wireless devices would be seen as if on one network.

Where might I explore how to make this come to be?

Comment: i'm no expert but sounds li you want one machine that connects to every Wifi hotspot and then somehow turn that into a router + wifi hotspot.  A bit of the guy with a shop surrounded by a shop on each side,  and he  labels his shop "Main Entrance"

Answer (score 1):

May be you have already setup this way; 
per your statement that your conclusion is to 1 Network. Built one machine, setup a router -( I for one prefer Linksys-cisco router), enable NAT, Install a second switch, and plug in your access points,camera,access controls to the switch.

All your access points should be on the same network. This as will includes all access controls, camera's etc.

are there any reasons to why you would want that on a virtual environment as this can be manageable through their web interfaces ?